# 1-1 correspondence between nuclei and regular monomorphisms of a locale

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, lattice-orders, topos-theory

I am having a little trouble with Theorem 2.3 in Professor Johnstone's book on "Stone Spaces". The theorem depends on a Lemma (which I am not struggling with; I only include it for context) which refers to a situation in which we have a locale A and a nucleus $j : A \rightarrow A$, and we have defined $A_j = \text{Im}\;j = \{ a \in A \;\mid\; j(a) = a \}$, and claim the following in Lemma 2.2:

> $A_j$ is a frame, and $j : A \rightarrow A_j$ is a frame homomorphism, whose right adjoint is the inclusion $A_j \rightarrow A$.

Now Professor Johnstone follows this with the Theorem of section 2.3:

> For any locale $A$, there is a bijection between nuclei on $A$ and regular subobjects of $A$ in **Loc** (i.e. isomorphism classes of regular monomorphisms $B \rightarrow A$)

Now in the proof for this Theorem, we are told that "given a nucleus $j$, Lemma 2.2 gives us a regular monomorphism $A_j \rightarrow A$". My issue with this statement is that, although the Lemma clearly shows that we have a homomorphism $j : A_j \rightarrow A$ in **Loc**, and one can quickly see that it is monic (because its dual in **Frm** is surjective by construction and so epi) it is not clear that this is a *regular* monomorphism in **Loc** (i interpret "$j$ is a *regular* monomorphism" to mean that $j$ is to be the equaliser of a pair of arrows in **Loc**).

After  a bit of pondering and a small amount of research on nlab, I guessed that the work needed to show $j$ is a regular monomorphism in **Loc** is to take its pushout along itself and then to prove that $j$ is the equaliser of those coprojections. I think this can be done in an elementary fashion by looking at the dual constructions in **Frm** (which seems to have pullbacks at least). Is that the correct / quickest approach or am I missing something obvious or more categorical in style? I'm wondering whether I should have been paying attention to something that Professor Johnstone might have written earlier in the book.

Comment: It's much easier to understand regular epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Frm}$: they are precisely the surjective frame homomorphisms.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Thanks. Professor Johnstone mentions same only a page before I should have been paying attention.  However he refers to [Manes 1976] "Algebraic Theories" for the background material and I wonder if I'll ever have the time to read that :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use that $j^2=j$. The diagram below is thus a coequalizer:
$$ A\underset{j}{\overset{{\rm id}}{\rightrightarrows}} A\to A_j\,.$$

**Update:** This answer is *wrong*, as commented below because $j:A\to A$ is not necessarily a frame morphism.

Comment: Whilst $ j : A \rightarrow A_j $ is an arrow in **Frm** I'm not convinced that (by composition with the inclusion) $ j : A \rightarrow A $ is, given that $ A $ and $ A_j $ have different joins in general. If that is the case, then how can the above be a diagram in **Frm** let alone a coequalizer?

Comment: It is true that the inclusion $A_j \to A$ is not a frame homomorphism. But its left adjoint $A \to A_j$ is.

Comment: Yes, but how does that make the diagram given by @Berci exist in **Frm** (I guess it works in the category of meet semilattices tho?)

Comment: Right. It doesn't really matter though: the point is that $A \to A_j$ is a surjective frame homomorphism, and every such is a regular epimorphism in $\mathbf{Frm}$.